# Allow users ability to "disable" a component in Spring integration-graph view within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.6.3.CI-B2266066, Build Id: 201411050946, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)) with Spring Integration 4.1.0.

I have a Spring configuration XML file that includes the Spring Integration namespace. Ideally I'd like a way to be able to easily `disable` a bunch of components.
Other ETL-type editors have similar functionality where you can "disable" something as opposed to having to actually comment-out something in code or in the config file.

In terms of how I'd envision that working I go back-and-forth on that.
 - Option A could be when the user selects a bunch of icons they could right-click and say `auto-start=false`.
 - Option B would be to have the spring-integration components all allow a new state called `disabled`.  This state is different from the auto-start state in that a disabled component
would not only never `auto-start` but it would also be by-passed within any flows it participated in.

Why would option B be useful?  Suppose you have the following flow:
`jms adapter -> transformerX -> transformerY -> output adapter`
If I could disable transformerY then people could easily basically "bypass" that step, in-essence making the flow look like this:
`jms adapter -> transformerX -> output adapter`

In either case, `disabling` or `auto-start=false` components might be shown as grayed-out on the integration-graph tab.

I'm sure this is not a trivial ask, but as I've mentioned other tools do off this and it comes in handy quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

While neither of the following address the IDE rendering, there are a couple of existing ways to implement your requirements:

Use profiles to replace the component with a `<bridge/>`...

```
<beans profile="on">
   <int:transformer input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" />
</bean>

<beans profile="off">
   <int:bridge input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" />
</bean>
```

Or use a [routing slip](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#routing-slip) to determine the components that a message will visit.

Option B would take quite a bit of work and I am not sure that turning on/off components mid-flow has much applicability. If you can come up with some concrete use cases that might have wide use, feel free to open a [new feature JIRA issue against INT](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

I don't know how practical option A is, but you can ask the STS guys via a [new feature request JIRA issue against IDE](https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE).

Comment: I've re-visited a bunch of the workflows my team has written in another ETL tool and can't find a decent use-case to share as a good "disable" component example that could not also just be covered with the existing "auto-start=false".  For option A I've opened this JIRA:  https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-1362